# Как исправить ошибку "Non-static method <method_name> should not be called statically"

Tags: php, yii2, исключения

Существует проект на YII2, который размещен на хостинге и работает без особых проблем. При развертывании на локальном сервере этого проекта при отображении главной страницы выскакивает такая ошибка:

[image: Ошибка]

Проблема в том, что вызывается нестатический метод, возвращающий в свою очередь результат работы другого статического метода.

```
    public function findRedirectByUrl($url)
    {
        return self::findOne(['old_url' => $url]);
    }
```

Я читал, что это исключение может выбрасываться если, например, версия PHP сменена на более новую, это где-то есть в описании перехода на другую версию в разделе "Изменения, ломающие обратную совместимость". Но проблема ясна, вопрос в том, возможно ли не исправляя код в проекте игнорировать данную ошибку. На продакшене все работает с версией PHP такой же как и на локальном сервере. Есть ли какие-то параметры, например в php.ini, способные исправить это?

Comment: На самом деле надо бы код модуля рефакторить, а почить можно, например так, (new Redirects())-> вместо Redirects::

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно поступить так:

```
$obj = new Redirects();
$redirects = $obj->findRedirectByUrl($url);
```

если нужно однократно, то можно "укоротить" запись

```
$redirects = (new Redirects())->findRedirectByUrl($url);
```

> Но проблема ясна, вопрос в том, возможно ли не исправляя код в проекте игнорировать данную ошибку.

В данном случае - можете, пока версия PHP позволяет. Поскольку "внутри" все равно вызывается статический метод и логика не будет нарушена. Ну а по "правильному" так делать конечно нельзя

Comment: Я так и делал, но зачем мне создавать объект, меняя код, если на продакшене все работает? Мне надо поменять параметры окружения на локалке. Как это сделать?

Comment: Такие конструкции еще работают, из-за совместимости со старыми версиями PHP, но выдают предупреждение (warning), что так делать нехорошо. Если у вас все работает и менять не собираетесь, то можете просто отключить сообщения об ошибках и предупреждениях d php.ini error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT & ~E_WARNING

Comment: Поскольку использую vagrant, не стал лезть в его php.ini. Просто добавил в index.php строку:

    error_reporting(~E_DEPRECATED);

Конечно тоже правка кода, но не отнимает столько времени как исправление всех подобных конфликтов в проекте, ради развертывания на локалке.

Comment: Просто однажды на хостинге обновят версию PHP, в которой warning для таких действий заменится на error и придется перелопачивать весь проект. Лучше заранее "подчищать" код по мере возможности

Comment: Спасибо за рекомендацию, думаю вы правы, правка кода проекта неизбежна.